# How to automation AWS Lambda/Data migration testing using selenium

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, aws-dms

I need to automate AWS DMS services using selenium, can someone please suggest is it possible to automate Amazon DMS testing using selenium.

I am required to test source data with target data in AWS DMS.

Comment: Your code trials please?

Comment: not yet started just want to know the feasibility, is it possible to do this? if yes then any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.